# Where should the access token be placed at successful login?

Tags: api, rest

I'm planning an API and  I haven't found any information about where the access token should be placed in the **response**. I'm interested in the case where I'm providing the access token. What is the best practice to send the token to the clients (from the backend service)?
Should it be sent to clients in the Header or in the Body of the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at examples and see what others do. For example, Facebook, Twitter, Google, Amazon... and all those popular PaaS services exposing a REST API all use OAuth2 as authentication mechanism:

In OAuth2 you'll see the specification requires to send the generated token to the client in the body of a json response: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5 . But you can also see how Google and other vendors extend this mechanism so it can be sent as a callback url param, for example (Check out https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent).

Once you get the authorization token you put it on the `Authorization:` HTTP header you send on your requests for accessing protected resources. They have to support this way of doing it, because it is how the OAuth2 standard specifies it https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-7

If you want to tinker a little bit more with oauth, check out https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

(OAuth is pretty much the same thing.)

They usually also extend the Authorization header mechanism to allow the token to be provided as a GET/POST parameter in the url or the body of the response, respectively (For example, Facebook's Graph API also supports [passing an access_token= parameter on your HTTP POST request body or GET URI](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens)). There is <strike>no way to manipulate or even read HTTP headers on a javascript browser application</strike> (see the modern [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) and other proposals on [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)), so providing this functionality makes life easier for many app developers.

Another popular authentication scheme is SOAP authentication. It doesn't support tokens but it supports digest authentication, which is a similar thing. The interesting part of it is that it is not HTTP/Web based (although it is primarily used that way), so you can use it over other application protocols. It's a little more cumbersome, but you can find ready to use implementations for both server and client.

You can also use [digest authentication over HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) without SOAP. It is also based on `Authorization:` headers and [every browser supports it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication). Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication to see how the authorization headers are formed in different ways depending on the level of security you want to reach.

Some services, like redmine, allow you to use an API token (API key) instead of a session token. Then you can make basic http auth on your requests like `https://whatever:yourapikey@example.com/protectedMethod`, although passing of auth data on URLs is currently deprecated in favor of basic auth header, and plain passwords / static API keys should only be sent over secured SSL connections. In this case the client can have the server generate an api key using a web interface or a rest api (so the generated key will be passed as a JSON response). This method may not be such a good idea, though: Check http://talks.codegram.com/http-authentication-methods#/intro if you want to know why, and also this question discussing where to put them: [Where should I place API keys in REST API calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388138/where-should-i-place-api-keys-in-rest-api-calls?rq=1)

Comment: You are talking about the case when I'm already logged in. I'm interested in the case where I'm providing the access token. What is the practice to send the token to the clients (from the back-end/server)? I update the question to make it clear :)

Comment: Oh, well, that is pretty much the same: In the case of oauth, for example, you'll see the specification requires to send the generated token to the client in the body of a json response: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-5 . But you can also see how Google and other vendors extend this mechanism so it can be sent as a callback url param, for example (Check out https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent). If you want to tinker a little bit more with oauth, check out https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/